# Customizing Semantic UI React font-family, but can't find src/site/globals/site.variables file to do so. Is there another way?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, google-font-api, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to change the global font-family for my app, but I can't get it to work.

I am using Semantic-UI-React so I figured that could be the problem, but when I looked for `src/site/globals/site.variables` (something other solutions have referenced) to change the global variables, I realized that I don't have those files inside the Semantic-UI-React node module. I also tried to use `!important` on the `#root` of my application as well as the `.app` that encloses all of my components and other lower levels too, but It only changes the code inside of my Semantic-Modal.

I imported the fonts in `frontend_react/public/index.html`

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:700,900');

  #root {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif !important;
  }
</style>

<title>Three Seeds Tarot</title>
```

I then called on the font in `/App.css`. I also called on it with the `body, html` selector in the same way and in the `page` selector to no avail.

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kX_5_Cqch4g/UmBAsMV4krI/AAAAAAAADjA/XEJnfAq1Dsg/s1600/ProtectionKamea300dpi(a3).jpg');
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif !important;
}
```

and here is my `/App.js` components render function:

```
render() {    
    const user = this.props.user

    return (
      <div className='App'>

        <div id='nav-bar'>
          <NavBar/> 
        </div>

        <div className='page'>

          {!user.loggedIn ? <div>
            <header className='App-header'>
              <marquee scrollamount='5' direction='right'><img src={image} className='App-logo' alt='logo' /></marquee>
            </header> 
          </div> : null 
          }

          <Switch>  
            <Route path='/readings/new' component={ NewReading } />
            <Route path='/readings' component={ ReadingSplash } />
            <Route path='/cards' component={ CardList }/> 
            <Route exact path='/profile' component={ Profile } />
            <Route exact path='/' component={ Welcome } />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={ Login } />
            <Route exact path='/signup' component={ Signup } />
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The only spot that the CSS changes have worked are in the `<p>` tags inside of my Semantic UI Modal:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div className='card-image'>

               <Modal 
               size='large'
               trigger={
                    <div className="ui medium images" > 
                        <img className="single-card" src={this.getImage(this.props.card.name)} alt="No Image Found" onClick={this.handleClick} />
                    </div>}
                style={inlineStyle.modal}
                >

                    <Modal.Header>{this.props.card.name}</Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Content >
                        <Image wrapped size='medium' src={this.getImage(this.props.card.name)} floated='left' />
                        <Modal.Description>
                            <Header>{capitalize(this.props.card.card_type)} Arcana</Header>
                            <p>Meaning Upright: {this.props.card.meaning_up} </p>
                            <p>Meaning Reversed: {this.props.card.meaning_rev} </p>
                            <p>Description: {this.props.card.desc} </p>
                        </Modal.Description>
                    </Modal.Content>
                    <Modal.Actions>
                        {/* <Button primary onClick={this.modalClose}>Close</Button> */}
                    </Modal.Actions>
                </Modal>

            </div>
        )
    }
```

So, to conclude, I want to change the global font. I tried using `!important` which I know isn't the best solution, but all of the other solutions I have found have references to changing the global variables for Semantic UI React in the `src/site/globals/site.variables` folder, which I don't seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

The `site.variables` file is a separate file in the Semantic UI build tools for the CSS. If your project is not also including the main Semantic UI project that includes all of the Gulp build tooling, you will not have any of those files. The only way to change that font would be to recompile your own CSS.

It sounds like you are importing the Semantic UI styles that are already compiled as a CSS import somewhere early in your application. As long as you define your desired font on the body tag AFTER your SUI import of the CSS it should take precedence. You could also combine selectors to increase specificity if you want to be sure.

```
body #root {
  font-family: "MyFont", ...your fallback stack 
}
```